# Trouble with calling methods from other classes

Tags: java

My code is not compiling and my biggest issue is that line 32 compiles but 42 does not and the methods they come from are written exactly the same. The error message is error cannot find symbol.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class CourseApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){    
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");

        int initialSize;
        boolean q = true;


        System.out.println("Enter how many courses you would like to enter info    rmation for? ");
        try{initialSize = s.nextInt();}
        catch(NumberFormatException sonic){
            while(initialSize <= 0){
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer greater than 0 (ie5). ");
                initialSize = s.nextInt();}}
        ArrayList <Course> courseArrayList = new ArrayList<Course> (initialSize);    

        String number="";
        String name="";
        String instr="";
        String text="";

        for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++){
            courseArrayList.add(new Course(number, name, instr, text));
            System.out.println("Enter in course information. ");
            do{
                courseArrayList.get(i).setNumber("");
                System.out.println("Please enter the course number: ");
                courseArrayList.get(i).setNumber(s.nextLine());
            }while(courseArrayList.get(i).getNumber().equals(""));
            do{
                courseArrayList.get(i).setName("");
                System.out.println("Please enter the course name: ");
                courseArrayList.get(i).setName(s.nextLine());
            }while(courseArrayList.get(i).getName().equals(""));
            do{
                courseArrayList.get(i).setLastName("");
                System.out.println("Please enter the Instructor's last name: ");
                courseArrayList.get(i).setLastName(s.nextLine());
            }while(courseArrayList.get(i).getLastName().equals(""));
            do{
                courseArrayList.get(i).setFirstName("");
                System.out.println("Please enter the Instructor's first name: ");
                courseArrayList.get(i).setFirstName(s.nextLine());
            }while(courseArrayList.get(i).getFirstName().equals(""));
            do{
                courseArrayList.get(i).setUserName("");
                System.out.println("Please enter the Instructor's user name: ");
                courseArrayList.get(i).setUserName(s.nextLine());
            }while(courseArrayList.get(i).getUserName().equals(""));
            String[] instrr = new String[3];
                instrr[0]=courseArrayList.get(i).getLastName()+", ";
                instrr[1]=courseArrayList.get(i).getFirstName()+"\n";
                instrr[2]=courseArrayList.get(i).getUserName()+"@K-State.ksu";
            instr = instrr[0]+instrr[1]+instrr[2];
            System.out.println("Please enter the required text book's title: ");
            courseArrayList.get(i).setTitle(s.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Please enter the required text book's author: ");
            courseArrayList.get(i).setAuthor(s.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Please enter the required text book's price: ");
            try{courseArrayList.get(i).setPrice(s.nextDouble());}
            catch(NumberFormatException shadow){
                while(courseArrayList.get(i).setPrice(s.nextDouble()) < 0){
                    System.out.println("Please enter a positive numerical value. ");
                    courseArrayList.get(i).setPrice(s.nextDouble());}}
            String[] textt = new String[3];
                textt[0]=courseArrayList.get(i).getTitle()+"\n";
                textt[1]=courseArrayList.get(i).getAuthor()+"\n";
                textt[2]=df.format(courseArrayList.get(i).getPrice())+"\n";
            text = textt[0]+textt[1]+textt[2];}

            for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++){
                System.out.println("Press enter to display each of the courses");
                s.nextLine();
                courseArrayList.get(i).toString();}

            System.out.println("Please enter a course number");
            String a = s.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++){
                if (a.equals(courseArrayList.get(i).getNumber())){
                    courseArrayList.remove(i);}
                else if (! a.equals(courseArrayList.get(initialSize-1).getNumber())){
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Course number not found.");
                        System.out.println("Please enter a valid course number: ");
                        a = s.nextLine();
                        for (int j = 0; j < initialSize; j++){
                            if (a.equals(courseArrayList.get(j).getNumber())){
                                q=false; 
                                courseArrayList.remove(j);}}
                    } while (q=true);}
                else {}}

            for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++){
                System.out.println("Press enter to display each of the courses");
                s.nextLine();
                courseArrayList.get(i).toString();}}}
```

this is from a different class and this part does not compile

```
public void setLastName(String lname){
    lastName=lname;}
```

the instructor class is:

```
public class Instructor
{
   private String lastName;     // Last name   
   private String firstName;    // First name
   private String userName;     // Username ID

    public Instructor(String lname, String fname, String un){
        lastName = lname;
        firstName = fname;
        userName = un;}

   public Instructor(Instructor object2){
        lastName = object2.lastName;
        firstName = object2.firstName;
        userName = object2.userName;}   

    public void setLastName(String lname){
        lastName=lname;}

    public String getLastName(){
            return lastName;}
    public void setFirstName(String fname){
        firstName=fname;}
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;}
    public void setUserName(String un){
            userName=un;}
    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;}

   public String toString()
   {
      return str;
   }
}
```

this is from a different class and this part does compile

```
 public void setName(String name){
  courseName=name;}
```

the course class is:

```
    public class Course
    {
       private String courseNumber;    // e.g. CIS 200
       private String courseName;      // e.g. Programming Fundamentals
       private Instructor instructor;  // Course instructor (object)
   private TextBook textBook;      // Required Course textbook (object)

   public Course(String number, String name, String instr, String text){
      courseNumber = number;
      courseName = name;
      instructor = new Instructor(instr);
      textBook = new TextBook(text);}

   public String getName(){
      return courseName;}

   public void setName(String name){
      courseName=name;}

   public String getNumber(){
      return courseNumber;}

   public void setNumber(String number){
      courseNumber=number;}

public Instructor getInstructor(){return new Instructor(instructor);}

    /**getTextBook method
    @return A reference to a copy of this course's TextBook object.*/

   public TextBook getTextBook(){return new TextBook(textBook);}

    /**toString method
    @return A string containing the course information.*/

    public String toString(){
        String str = courseNumber + " " + courseName+ "\n"+
        instr+"\n" +
        text;
        return str;}}
```

And finally the TextBook class:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TextBook
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
   private String title;    // Title of the book
   private String author;   // Author's last name
   private double price;    // Wholesale cost of the book

   public TextBook(String t, String a, double p){
      title = t;
      author = a;
      price = p;}

   public TextBook(TextBook object2){
      title = object2.title;
      author = object2.author;
      price = object2.price;}

   public void setTitle(String t){
      title=t;}
   public void setAuthor(String a){
      author=a;}
   public void setPrice(String p){
      price=p;}

   public void getTitle(){
      return title;}
   public void getAuthor(){
      return author;}
   public void getPrice(){
      return price;}

   public String toString(){
String str = "Required Textbook: \n" + "     " + title+", " + author + ", " + df.format(price);
          return str;}}
```

why does .setLastName() not work but .setName() does

Comment: @peeskillet: That doesn't seem right. To the original poster, please share your Course class code.

Comment: How can we help if you don't even tell us what's the error message when the compilation fails?

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

In your class that has this

```
public void setLastName(String lname){
    lastName=lname;
}
```

Make sure `lastName` exists as class variable. I am guessing this should be like:

```
private String lastName;
```

If you post your Course.java code, we all would be better equipped to explain what might be missing.